# Can I configure Dita-OT 2.1 to output only the topic.fo file and not the pdf

Tags: dita, dita-ot

Is there a method when creating dita-ot 2.1 pipeline to only output the 
topic.fo and not go on to create the PDF?

Regards
Conteh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such a parameter available by default.
If you look in the ANT build file "DITA-OT/plugins/org.dita.pdf2/build.xml" there is a "transform.fo2pdf" target. I guess you could manually make changes to the build file in order to avoid calling this target from the "transform.topic2pdf" target.

Change:

```
   <target name="transform.topic2pdf" depends="copyCoreArtwork,transform.topic2fo,transform.fo2pdf"/>
```

To:

```
<target name="transform.topic2pdf" depends="copyCoreArtwork,transform.topic2fo"/>
```